# Access private data member from a subclass

Tags: java, oop, visibility, encapsulation

I would like to declare a data member of a superclass, private:

```
public abstract class superclass {
  private int verySensitive;

  abstract int setVerySensitive(int val); // must be overriden by subclass to work properly
}


public class subclass extends superclass {

  @Override
  protected int setVerySensitive(int val) {
    if (val > threshLow && val < threshHigh) // threshHigh is calculated in superclass constructor
       verySensitive = val;
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have a problem here: superclass can't access verySensitive because it's private, but I don't want to make verySensitive protected because it's... sensitive.

Also note that setVerySensitive was made abstract because checking against valid values can only be done after superclass has been constructed.

Can you recommend an elegant way of getting out of this "catch 22" situation?

Comment: isn't this a _feature_ of the language?  you're only option is setting to protected if it needs to be inherited

Comment: @Greg Flynn You are correct, in C++ this isn't an issue because protected data members can be accessed by the subclass while still hidden from users of the class. In Java, protected makes it available to the entire package, not just the superclass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest something like this:

```
public abstract class superclass {
  private int verySensitive;

  final int setVerySensitive(int val) {
    if (checkVerySensitive(val)) {
      verySensitive = val;
    }
  }
  protected abstract boolean checkVerySensitive(int val);
}


public class subclass extends superclass {

  @Override
  protected boolean checkVerySensitive(int val) {
    return val > threshLow && val < threshHigh; // threshHigh is calculated in superclass constructor
  }
}
```

This is similar to EboMike's suggestion, but it leaves `setVerySensitive(int)` with package access instead of making it private.

Comment: This is the most practical solution so far. +1

Answer (score 6):

How about making the checking abstract, but the setting itself private?

```
public abstract class superclass {
  private int verySensitive;

  abstract boolean verifySensitiveValue(int val); // must be overriden by subclass to work properly

  private void setVerySensitiveValue(int val) {
    if (verifySensitiveValue(val)) {
      verySensitive = val;
    }
  }
}


public class subclass extends superclass {

  @Override
  protected boolean verifySensitiveValue(int val) {
    return (val > threshLow && val < threshHigh); // threshHigh is calculated in superclass constructor
  }
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution, if users of the superclass could actually call setVerySensitiveValue(). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use reflect:

```
// SubClass.java
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class SuperClass {
    private String privateField = "This is Private";
    public SuperClass(){
    }
}
class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    void getPrivateField(){
        Field f = null;
        try {
            f = SuperClass.class.getDeclaredField("privateField");
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException nsfe){
            throw new Error();
        }
        f.setAccessible(true);
        try {
            System.out.println(f.get(this));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException iae){
            throw new Error();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new SubClass().getPrivateField();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the only answer that fits your criteria would be this:

```
public abstract class superclass {
  private int verySensitive;

  abstract int setVerySensitive(int val); // must be overriden by subclass to work properly

  protected void setVerySensitiveForReal(int val) {
    verySensitive = val;
  }
}


public class subclass extends superclass {

  @Override
  protected int setVerySensitive(int val) {
    if (val > threshLow && val < threshHigh) // threshHigh is calculated in superclass constructor
       setVerySensitiveForReal(val);
  }
}
```

It's not much different than simply making `verySensitive` protected but you have to be able to access it *somewhere*.

Comment: What if another programmer in the team calls setVerySensitiveForReal() by mistake with a dangerous value?

Answer (score 1):

sorry, no way out.

Either it is private and only you can access it, or it is protected and it is part of your subclass signature.

Answer (score 1):

Just how "sensitive" is this value? You may want to look into configuring a SecurityManager to prevent accessing the private field via reflection.

http://aminurrashid.com/english/java/core-java/prevent-reflection-to-access-private-methods-and-members-in-java-classes.html

Comment: Thanks for introducing reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a protected method the child class can access for actually change verySensitive value.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
protected void setVerySensitive(int val) { verySensitive = val; }
```

in the superclass, then use that in the subclass to set the value.

Comment: setVerySensitive must be abstract because checking against valid values can only be done after superclass has been constructed.

Comment: No, the superclass method is protected and is used ONLY by the subclass to actually change the value, assuming the validation is being done in the subclass methods.